# Confusion regarding definition of regular function

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is quoted from Basic algebraic geometry Shafervich.

> Let X be a closed set in the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ over the ground field $k$. A function f defined on X with values in $k$ is regular if there exists a
>   polynomial $F(T)$ with coefficients in $k$ such that $f (x)=F(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

I do not understand the definition at all. How is this different from a polynomial function?

Isn't this just a polynomial function?

Comment: Essentially. But you are defining what it means for the function $f$ - which lives on $X$ - to be regular. It means that the values of $f$ agree with the values of some polynomial when you restrict the values of that polynomial to the geometric object $X$.

Comment: @JohnMartin : Sorry but i still do not understand...

Comment: @KittyL : I think you should make it an answer... $f(x,y)$ is any function on $\mathbb{A}^2$ or a subset of $\mathbb{A}^2$.. We say $f(x,y)$ is regular on $X$ if, when restricted to $X$, $f(x,y)=F(x,y)$ for some polynomial $F(x,y)\in k[x,y]$..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, let $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}, F(x,y)=xy$. Define $X=V(x^2+y^2-1)$. Then $f(x,y)=xy=F(x,y)$ when restricted to the affine variety $X$. So $f(x,y)$ is a regular function on $X$, but it is not a polynomial function defined on $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Comment: $f(x,y)$ should be defined on a bigger subset than $X$??

Comment: @topgeomj: It doesn't have to be. This is just an example. It could be defined just on $X$. For example, if $X=\{0, 1\}$ in $\mathbb{A}^1$, and $f(x)$ is defined to be $1$ at $x=0$, $2$ at $x=1$, then it is a regular function since it is equal to $F(x)=x+1$ in $k[x]$. You can see with this example, $f(x)$ could be any function. You can always find a polynomial $F(x)$ that agrees with $f(x)$ at $X$.

Comment: Yes.. I got it now..

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct. But think about this. Consider the closed set $V(x) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$. $f=xy$ and $g=0$ are different polynomials (in the ring $k[x, y]$); however, they both define the same regular function on $V(x)$. The idea is that a regular function is a function from your closed set $X$ to $k$, and it happens to coincide with some polynomial function. 
The example above shows that there are many polynomials representing a regular function. In fact, later you'll see if $X$ is an affine variety in $\mathbb{A}^n$, then the collection of regular functions on $X$ can be identified with $k[x_1, \dots, x_n] / I(X)$, where $I(X)$ is the ideal of polynomials in $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ vanishing on $X$.

Comment: Thanks.. So, you are saying that $f(x,y)$ need not be defined on whole affine plane?

Comment: In the definition you quoted, a regular function is defined on a closed _subset_ $X$ of $\mathbb{A}^n$ (where affine space has the Zariski topology). Of course $X$ could be all of $\mathbb{A}^n$.